# How to get sub-document record in mongo shell

Tags: java, mongodb

I have the following document in :

```
 "Demo" : {
            "SI" : {
                "Value1" : 40,
                "Value2" : [ 
                    10, 
                    15, 
                    20

                ]
            } ,
            "RS" : {
                "Value1" : 4,
                "Value2" : [ 
                    1, 
                    2, 
                    3, 
                    4
                ]
                }
    }
```

I want to fetch the data for sub-document 'SI'. I have tried with following query: 
    `db.getCollection('input').find({"Demo.SI":"SI"})`, but its not giving any record for 'SI' document. The desired output is:

```
"SI" : {
            "Value1" : 40,
            "Value2" : [ 
                10, 
                15, 
                20

            ]
        }
```

Please specify where the query goes wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First check`SI` exists or not using `$exists` and then add it in `projection` as below :

```
db.input.find({"Demo.SI":{"$exists":true}},{"Demo.SI":1,"_id":0}).pretty()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
db.collection.find({ "Demo.SI": { $exists: true, $ne: null } },{"Demo.SI":1,"_id":0})
```

This query will return all the documents which has SI key